# Why am I unable to send text file stored in my app's internal storage?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I have an App say(app A) in which I have stored a text file (testfile.txt) in internal storage (data/data/com.example.mockapp/files) through the code.

```
// Create a file in the Internal Storage
        String content = "hello world";
        String filename="testfile.txt";
        File file = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        try {
            file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("InternalfileException", "we are here in exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It is confirmed that file got created succesfully and it exists ( I have checked)

Note : using file provider to share text file.

//XML

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path path="." name="mockfiles" />
</paths>
```

//MANIFEST

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.mock.fileprovider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

//THIS IS CODE IN MAIN ACTIVITY TO SEND INTENT

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.mock.fileprovider", file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, null));
```

**Now when I launch the app** , it pops up chooser dialog with watsapp , gmail,message etc for options but

when I click on any of them it just shows ..

*1) in case of watsapp -- shows txt file but it never completes uploading*

*2) in case of gmail  -- shows txt file which never gets attached as attachment, empty mail is sent.*

what am i missing?

this has made me crazy till now.

kindly help..

Comment: Read the part here about getting the right URI and granting temporary permissions: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#Permissions

Comment: If you are running on API Level 15 or lower, [you have more work to do to grant the permissions](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html). Also, [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper) helps with some flawed clients.

Comment: @KenWolf , intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
is this not enough.?

Comment: Um, API Level 20 is Android 4.4W, and I really doubt that you are running this code on a 1st-generation Android Wear device.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Sorry , my bad, API level is 16. kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has something to do with `file permissions` , sorted that out.
Try to provide proper `read` `write` permission, for this to work. Also make sure 
you declare file provider in `manifest` properly.

thanks!

Comment: I'm facing same issue, can you please help on this

Answer (score 0):

I had de same problem and finally I I found the solution in this page:
https://jayrambhia.com/blog/android-fileprovider-ecosystem

This is the code that worked for me. It's done in **Kotlin**, but it's quite similar:

```
//name of document
                val nombre = getString(R.string.app_name).replace(" ", "_")

                //saving document in internal storage
                contexto!!.openFileOutput("$nombre.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
                    it.write("holita".toByteArray())
                }

                //Generation Uri
                val path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    contexto!!,
                    "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider",
                    File(contexto!!.filesDir, "My_Password_Saver.txt")
                )

                //Sharing document
                val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path)
                    type = "text/plain"
                }

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Enviar"))
```